# How to convert a CSV entry from a String to an Expression?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, csv-format

I have a list that looks like this:

```
{{"74.28300000000003,90.32258064516131"},{"75.06400000000004,92.90322580645163"}}
```

To be able to use these in a `ListPlot`, I need to convert this CSV data to numbers while retaining the list structure. The correct format looks basically the same but without the quotation marks.

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: `expr /. {str_String} :> ToExpression@StringSplit[str, ","]`

Comment: `alist = {{"74.28300000000003,90.32258064516131"}, \
{"75.06400000000004,92.90322580645163"}}` and `Interpreter[DelimitedSequence["Number"]][#] & /@ alist`

Answer (score 4):

You can try `ImportString`

```
csvStrings = {{"74.28300000000003,90.32258064516131"}, {"75.06400000000004,92.90322580645163"}};

csvData = First@ImportString[#, "CSV"]&@@@csvStrings 
(*{{74.28300000000003`,90.32258064516131`},{75.06400000000004`,92.90322580645163`}}*)

ListPlot@csvData
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thanks!